# SUBSTR() in MYSQl

Tags: mysql

How to remove characters from end from any column in MYSQl using SUBSTR ?

For example:
Suppose column value is `1221213.2`, so I want to achieve `1221213`.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(colname,1,-2) FROM tablename.
```

Comment: Are we certain the column name in question is varchar?  if numeric a round would work `round(colName,0)`  Data types and functions available matter.  So string functions generally don't work on numeric data types without doing some implicit or explicit conversions; which can be risky.

Answer (score 1):

It's this query (assuming your 'remove' is update data in DB):

```
UPDATE tablename SET colname=SUBSTR(colname, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(colname)-1)
```

-this will remove `1` symbol from end of string. (so, `SUBSTR(colname, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(colname)-2)` for 2 sumbols - you've updated)

(upd. there are suggestions for `LEFT()` function, it's better. I will not repeat that code, however).

Answer (score 0):

It work for firebirb:

```
select substr(p.name, 1, strlen(rtrim(p.name))-2) from products p
```

I think for MySQL `strlen` need replaced with [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(colname, CHARACTER_LENGTH(colname)-2);
```

Prefer [`CHARACTER_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_character-length) over [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_length) to avoid surprises.

Now it looks like you are trying to [truncate the decimal digits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_truncate) from a decimal number. This is what you might be looking for instead:

```
SELECT TRUNCATE(colname, 0);
```

And to update your table:

```
UPDATE tablename SET colname = TRUNCATE(colname, 0); -- or LEFT(...), or whatever approach you choose
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LEFT function.

```
select LEFT(colname, LENGTH(colname)-2);
```

LEFT(str, len) selects number of characters from left of the string specified.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers all assume that you always want to remove the last 2 characters. But what if there's more (or less) significant digits after the period?

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    colname = SubStr(colname, 0, Locate('.', colname))
WHERE  Locate('.', colname) > 0
```

**UPDATE**

Even better method:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    colname = SubString_Index(colname , '.', 1)
WHERE  Locate('.', colname) > 0
```

Comment: `CHARINDEX()` must be a custom alias. The standard function name is [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate). Also, does not work if there is no "`.`" in the input string (but yes this is out of scope).

Comment: @RandomSeed apologies, `CharIndex()` is a SQL Server function. Have changed this to `Locate()`... As for the failure: the `WHERE` clause will filter out any records who do not contain a period.